# Exporting multiple tables to excel with Bootstrap data-export

Tags: excel, export, bootstrap-table

I have three different tables as seen in the picture. I have a problem when I want to export them. It writes Table 1, then writes Tables 1 and 2, and finally Tables 1, 2 and 3.

Tables `<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-export"> ... </table>`

Button code    `<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-login hide-print" data-export="excel"  data-export-name="Exprt" data-export-type="xls"><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Export</span></a>`

[image]

How can I properly export these tables in a single worksheet?

the export i want

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "properly export"? if you want them merged maybe you can merge them in bootstrap before export (i don't know Bootstrap, just guessing). Show some sample of what you expect...

Comment: I edited the post and added the sample image @Apostolos55

Comment: As I understand this is a matter of the export procedure, aka Bootstrap. Therefor you must seek the answer there... Excel and VBA can clear the data for you, but it is much more difficult to do.